# Clean Up After a Java8 Stream

Tags: java, stream, java-8, java-stream

When I start with an unbounded Stream and use the limit() method to put a bound on it, how can I clean up the resources that were used by the Stream once the limit is reached?  For example, if I'm trying to do what the Files.lines method does, but with floats instead of strings, I would write a function that looks something like this:

```
public static Stream<Float> floats(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        return Stream.generate(() -> {

            byte[] buff = new byte[4];
            try { fis.read(buff); }
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            return ByteBuffer.wrap(buff).getFloat(0);

        }).limit(f.length()/4);
    }
```

This should stream a large binary file full of floats until I reach the end of the file.  I divide the length of the file in bytes by the four bytes that make up a float.  However, I'd like to find some way to execute fis.close() once this limit is reached.  Does the Streams API have any way of letting you do this?

Comment: Could provide an `onClose` that closes `fis` and document your method to say it returns a `Stream` that must be closed.

Comment: Your exception handling is more than questionable.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another possibility.  It's kind of a hack, but it seems to work.  I just run the Stream through a filter that always returns true, but in the process of doing so, it checks for EOF and closes the input stream if it's reached.  I was hoping there was a cleaner way to do this built into the API.

```
    Stream<Float> answer;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

    answer = Stream
            .generate(() -> {
                byte[] buff = new byte[4];
                try { fis.read(buff); }
                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                return ByteBuffer.wrap(buff).getFloat(0);})
            .filter(x -> { 
                try { if (fis.available() == 0) fis.close(); } 
                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                return true;})
            .limit(f.length()/4);

    return answer;
```

Comment: Why don't you use onClose(), as suggested by Sotirios? And why did you accept Rafael's answer, which is clearly wrong?

Comment: I didn't realize it was wrong when I accepted it and the onClose way would work, but I don't want to have to create a new class with an additional method that needs the be called after the Stream reaches its limit.  I want a single Stream object that takes care of clean-up internally.

Comment: Why would you need to write another class? `stream.onClose(() -> { try { fis.close(); } catch(IOException e) { throw new UncheckedIOException(e); } })`. BTW, InputStream.available() doesn't do what you think it does. You should never use that method.

Comment: BTW, the code in my previous comment is exactly what Files.lines() uses.

Comment: Oh, okay.  I misunderstood where the onClose method was supposed to be.

Comment: I'm trying this and never seeing the "Closing fis" output:  stream.onClose(() -> { try { fis.close(); System.out.println("Closing fis"); } catch(IOException e) { throw new UncheckedIOException(e); } }).  It's hard to fit neatly-organized code into comments.

Comment: That means you forgot to close the stream when you're done with it, in the code calling your method, and consuming the stream.

Answer (score 0):

I’d use an entirely different approach:

```
public static Stream<Float> floats(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try(FileChannel fch = FileChannel.open(f.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
        ByteBuffer  bb = fch.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fch.size());
        FloatBuffer fb = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        return IntStream.range(0, fb.remaining()).mapToObj(fb::get);
    }
    catch(IOException ex) { // or consider to declare "throws IOException" instead
        FileNotFoundException fnfe = new FileNotFoundException(ex.getMessage());
        fnfe.initCause(ex);
        throw fnfe;
    }
}
```

with this, the `FileChannel` has been closed already when the method returns. It’s also potentially more efficient. Note that for a lot of operations, it might be more efficient to process the data as `DoubleStream`, even when the source values are `float`s and only narrow the type of the final result back to `float`, if necessary:

```
public static DoubleStream floatsAsDouble(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try(FileChannel fch = FileChannel.open(f.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
        ByteBuffer  bb = fch.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fch.size());
        FloatBuffer fb = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        return IntStream.range(0, fb.remaining()).mapToDouble(fb::get);
    }
    catch(IOException ex) { // or consider to declare throwsIOException instead
        FileNotFoundException fnfe = new FileNotFoundException(ex.getMessage());
        fnfe.initCause(ex);
        throw fnfe;
    }
}
…
    float sum=(float)floatsAsDouble(new File("path")).sum();
```

Also, you may consider to directly work with `Path`s instead of `File`.

Comment: Wouldn't both of these close the file channel as soon as return will be invoked? And wouldn't that then make it so the `fb::get` operates on closed resource, and thus does not work?

Comment: @M. Prokhorov: that’s even stated in my answer: “*with this, the `FileChannel` has been closed already when the method returns*”. Which is intentional to avoid having to close anything later-on. The important point can be found in the [documentation of `FileChannel.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map-java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode-long-long-): “*A mapping, once established, is not dependent upon the file channel that was used to create it. Closing the channel, in particular, has no effect upon the validity of the mapping.*”

Comment: I see. So it will create a ByteBuffer that points to wherever the Channel was pointing to, as in to the place on a disk, correct?

Comment: @M. Prokhorov: it’s the same underlying file as represented by the channel and the range passed as arguments to `map`. How the memory area is synced with the file is implementation dependent, but usually, since all operations on the file go through the os, the mapped memory is identical to the system’s I/O buffers and will reflect all changes immediately.